# PHP PDO: SQLSTATE[08S01] SQLConnect: -829 [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]TLS handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, pdo, odbc, sqlanywhere

Our database vendor recently changed to using TLS encryption (our Windows ODBC connections were previously unencrypted).  The ODBC data sources are set up in Windows and are connecting without issue (as they did before, but now they're connecting correctly with the TLS encryption).

My impression is that PDO_ODBC uses the Windows data source to connect and isn't forming a connection independent of the data source.  PHP PDO, however, is tossing the error:

> SQLSTATE[08S01] SQLConnect: -829 [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]TLS
> handshake failure

Even though the Windows data sources are all tested and working correctly.

This is the connection function:

```
function c_connect() {  

    global $pdo_conn;   
    
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $dsn = "odbc:My_ODBC"; //changed for security
    $odbcusername = "user"; //changed for security
    $odbcpassword = "password"; //changed for security
    
    try {   
        //Connection String
        $pdo_conn = new PDO($dsn, $odbcusername, $odbcpassword);
                
        //Initiate Error Detection
        $pdo_conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );   

    }
    
    catch(Exception $e)  {   
        echo "Invalid Connection: ";
        die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );  
    }
}
```

I've been searching all over and cannot find any information about what needs to be done here.  It seems like the PDO connection may need to be adjusted to accommodate the TLS encryption change even though the ODBC connections are working without issue, but I'm not finding any specifics on what needs to be done.

Comment: Perhaps someone can help you, but even so, I can easily come up with stuff that isn't mentioned in your question. For instance, which OS you're running. Windows perhaps? You say: _"Our ODBC connections are connecting without issue."_, but how do these "ODBC connections" differ from the PDO connection that doesn't work? Another example, you say: _"Our database vendor recently changed to using TLS encryption"_, so what did it use before? No encryption? More so, the whole DSN is missing? Basically you're assuming someone here is super familiar with your problem and doesn't need much information.

Comment: Mayby this can help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Great points, KIKO, thank you.  I edited my initial post with your suggested corrections!  Reading the article now.

Both before and after, the Windows ODBC data sources are tested in working, but after the encryption was set up the PHP is failing with the stated error.

Comment: Thanks for the article, KIKO, I'm not seeing anything in there that I can implement in this specific situation.

Comment: I've found some kind of [driver for SAP SQL Anywhere](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_SQLANYWHERE), not sure it's useful, and [another forum](https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the helpful links, KIKO!